# Is there a way to compare a lot of files in one directory using the diff command?

Tags: shell

I already tried this. (I specified the directory using cd at the beginning of my code)

```
    for ((i=0; i<=90; i++))
    do
        if [[ "$(diff -r * *)" -eq 0 ]]
        then
            printf "files dont differ. \n"
        else
            printf "files differ. \n"
        fi
    done
```

This gives me the error "diff: extra operand ''"
The files are all shellscripts with random code in them and I want to compare them all (2 at a time) to find files that are identical.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare the files just to find out whether they are identical, you can also use `cmp` instead of `diff`.

If you really want to have a line of output for every pair of files, differing as well as identical, you can generate the pairs with two nested loops, e. g.

```
set -- *
while [ "$1" ]
do  file1="$1"
    shift
    for file2 in "$@"
    do  if cmp -s "$file1" "$file2"
        then echo $file1 and $file2 don\'t differ.
        else echo $file1 and $file2 differ.
        fi
    done
done
```

(If you wouldn't need output for differing files, a more sophisticated way of selecting files to compare based on their length could be taken.)